# Getting Error when uploading .ipa file to application loader

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, application-loader

I am developing Xamarin Ios app.I am getting the below error when upload .ipa file to application loader.And i dont have Ipad pro in my Info.plist like below:
[image]

how can i solve this please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered some weird behaviour with this icon size as well related to Visual Studio.

Make sure you have another icon named `Icon-83.5@2x.png` in your `Resources` folder and set the build action to `BundleResource`.

Now rebuild your project. Check in the `info.plist` file if you have a entry like this: `<string>Icon-83.5@2x.png</string>`.
If you do you can submit that ipa. If it isn't in there, put it in manually under the `CFBundleIconFiles` key and then rebuild again.

```
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
        <string>Icon-72@2x.png</string>
        <string>Icon-72.png</string>
        <string>Icon@2x.png</string>
        <string>Icon.png</string>
        <string>Icon-60@2x.png</string>
        <string>Icon-76.png</string>
        <string>Icon-76@2x.png</string>
        <string>Icon-83.5@2x.png</string>
        <string>Default-568h@2x.png</string>
        <string>Icon-Small-50@2x.png</string>
        <string>Icon-Small-50.png</string>
        <string>Icon-Small-40.png</string>
        <string>Icon-Small-40@2x.png</string>
        <string>Icon-Small.png</string>
        <string>Icon-Small@2x.png</string>
    </array>
```

Double-check that the entry wasn't erased by the build process. If it wasn't submit your ipa to the store.

Downside to all of this is, as I have encountered it, is that the entry gets deleted from the list by the build process. Or more specifically, when I change anything in the project options that influences the `info.plist` file.

Another way to go about this is to switch to a Asset Catalog.